# How can i know the length of one sentence in the users input - NOT THE WHOLE INPUT - Just the sentence

Tags: python

```
import sys

# what does the program do
#   1- Recieve input from the user about what sentence does he want to write.
#   2- Recieve input from the user about WHAT sentences you want the system to write out using WHAT?.
#   3- Make a list about each sentence length.
#   4- Make if conditionals if any word from the alphabet exists in the sentence.
#   5- If that word existed it's gonna try to print it from the if conditional.
#   6- Make spaces betweeen each word with "------"
#   7- At last Print it
while true:
    # input the user what does the sys want to type + what words
    print("_" * 10)
    words = input("What do you want the system to write?:  ")
    material = input("With what words (it can be 1 word or a sentence):  ")
    thick = input("Alrite it's made out of {} then how thick can it be - give it a try!:  ").format(material)
    # Back-end of the program
```

what am trying to do is that i want to make a program that writes the user sentences in a special way
I'm doing this because i finished a python crashcourse and am making the ideas stick so i can do Machine Learning Then progress with other languages.
Thanks

**Isotope**

Comment: I think it's a bit unclear, at least for me. Could you give a sample output of what you'd like?

Comment: You need to clarify the definition of a sentence.  For example, it is probably terminated by a specific character, for example `[\!\.\?]`, then use something like `re.split()` on those characters (I have escaped those characters for safety, that might not be necessary).  Then just use `len()` on the first sentence to get the number of characters.

Comment: Thanks man a way to go!